# Passing Data to custom adapter from asyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am taking an online course and making an android application for my self learning. In this application I want to show thumbnails of movie posters in a gridView. Now my question is how can I pass my `movies arrayList` to custom adapter from `asyncTask`. Is there something I can achieve in `onPostExecute` method. I mean how can I set data source for my adapter asynchronously in `onPostExecute` method of asyncTask?
here is my code.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FetchMovies mMovies = new FetchMovies(this);
        mMovies.execute("popularity.desc");
        GridView gridView= (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this,new ArrayList<MovieContract>()));
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }}
```

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<MovieContract> movie_list;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MovieContract> movie_list) {
        mContext = context;
        this.movie_list= movie_list;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movie_list.size();
    }
    @Override
    public MovieContract getItem(int position) {

        return movie_list.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
           Picasso.with(mContext).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" + movie_list.get(position).getMovie_poster()).into(imageView);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
     //      imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }}
```

```
public class FetchMovies extends AsyncTask<String,Void,ArrayList<MovieContract>> {


private  CustomAdapter customAdapter;

private Context context;

private ArrayList<MovieContract> mMovie_list = new ArrayList<>();

private MovieContract mMovieContract;

private  String poster_path;



public final String LOG_Tag=FetchMovies.class.getSimpleName();

public FetchMovies(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected ArrayList doInBackground(String[] params) {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String MoviesJsonStr = null;

    String  Api_key= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    try {

        final String Movies_base="http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?";
        final String Sort_param="sort_by";
        final String ApiKey_param="api_key";
        final String Image_Size="w500";

        Uri MovieUriBuilder=Uri.parse(Movies_base).buildUpon()
                                .appendQueryParameter(Sort_param,params[0])
                                .appendQueryParameter(ApiKey_param, Api_key)
                                .build();

        Log.v(LOG_Tag, "URI Builder" + MovieUriBuilder.toString());

        URL url=  new URL(MovieUriBuilder.toString());
        urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        InputStream inputStream= urlConnection.getInputStream();
        StringBuffer buffer= new StringBuffer();
        if(inputStream==null){
            MoviesJsonStr=null;
        }

       reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String Result;
        while ((Result=reader.readLine())!=null){
            buffer.append(Result + '\n');

        }

        if (buffer.length() == 0) {

            MoviesJsonStr = null;
        }
        MoviesJsonStr = buffer.toString();
        Log.v(LOG_Tag,"Forecast Jason String " + MoviesJsonStr);

    }


    catch (IOException e){

        Log.e("FetchMovies", "Error ", e);
        MoviesJsonStr=null;


    }


    finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
            }
        }
    }


    try {

        return ParseMoviesJsonString(MoviesJsonStr);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}


private ArrayList<MovieContract> ParseMoviesJsonString(String movieJsonStr ) throws JSONException{

    final String json_result="results";
    final String json_poster_path="poster_path";
    final String json_original_title="original_title";
    final String json_title="title";
    final String json_releaseDate="release_date";
    final String json_overview="overview";
    final String json_vote_average="vote_average";

    ArrayList<MovieContract> movie_list= new ArrayList<>();

    JSONObject MovieJson = new JSONObject(movieJsonStr);
    JSONArray MovieArray = MovieJson.getJSONArray(json_result);

    String[] resultStrs = new String[MovieArray.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < MovieArray.length(); i++) {



        //JSONObject Movieobject = MovieArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject result_movie=MovieArray.getJSONObject(i);
        MovieContract movie = new MovieContract();
        movie.setTitle(result_movie.getString(json_original_title));
        movie.setMovie_poster(result_movie.getString(json_poster_path));
        movie.setPlot_synopsis(result_movie.getString(json_overview));
        movie.setRelease_date(result_movie.getString(json_releaseDate));
        movie.setVote_average(result_movie.getString(json_vote_average));

        movie_list.add(movie);





    }
    for (MovieContract result : movie_list){

        Log.v(LOG_Tag," preparing data " + result.getMovie_poster() +  "  " +result.getPlot_synopsis() );
    }



    return movie_list;

}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<MovieContract> Movie_list) {


}}
```

Comment: can you add your async task code

Comment: Yes..just give me 5 min.

Comment: @MaheshGiri i have added `asynctask` code could you plz take a look at it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a your CustomAdapter as an instance variable in the activity:

```
private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
```

Create the Adapter and set the RecyclerView adapter this way:

```
customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,new ArrayList<MovieContract>());
gridView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Create an update data method for your CustomAdapter:

```
public void updateMovies(ArrayList<MovieContract> movie_list) {
    this.movie_list= movie_list;
}
```

Then in onPostExecute:

```
customAdapter.updateMovies(movie_list);
customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem now images are showing in gridview. `notifyDataSetChanged()` did the magic.

Comment: Sorry..reallly forgot to do that one. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I always do this to make async task more usable

create an Object in your async task class

OnResult onresult;

in your Async task create an interface

```
public interface OnResult{

public void onfinishprogress(ArrayList<> resultlist);

}


//create a method in async task

public void setOnResult(OnResult onresult)
{

this.onresult=onresult;

}
```

in your onPostExecute(..) set the result

```
onPostExecute(ArrayList<MovieContract> Movie_list){

if(this.onresult!=null)
   this.onresult.onfinishprogress(Movie_list);

}
```

now come how to get the result in MainActivity

```
FetchMovies fmv=FetchMovies();
fmv.execute(url);
//now get the result from the interface created above

fmv.setOnResult(new OnResult(){

onfinishprogress(ArrayList<> resultlist)
{
    //here you get the resultlist which you passed up there.    
   gridView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
}

});
```